# Não consigo iniciar o Xampp

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, xampp

Ao tentar iniciar o MySQL no xampp como sempre de costume, ocorreu este erro:

```php
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:04:23  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:04:23  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:04:23  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:04:23  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:04:23  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:04:23  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Já olhei em alguns lugares para tentar resolver, mas nenhum desses métodos resolveu:

- Abrir o gerenciador de tarefas e encerrar o precesso mysqld (Ele não aparece no meu gerenciador).
- Ir para `C:\xampp\mysql\data` e apagar os arquivos aria_log, ib_buffer, ib_logfile, ibdata1, multi-master, mysql_error e etc (Ao apagar e tentar iniciar o MySQL, eles são criados novamente).
- Alterar uma porta do Skype, mas não tenho ele instalado.

Se desinstalar e instalar vou perder meus bancos de dados, estou meio preocupado com essa situação kkk, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Provavelmente tem dois mysqls instalados na sua máquina, a porta do skype não tem nada haver com isto, só quando é o apache que estiver com erro, o teu caso é o mysql que esta com problema.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize no CMD o comando: netstat -a -n -o | findstr porta do mysql, caso ela esteja em uso, mate-a e tente novamente: Taskkill /PID pid /F (alterar pid pelo número que o netstat forneceu).

Comment: Infelizmente ela não está em uso, pior que não posso desinstalar porquê se não vou perder todos bds.

Comment: e se fizer uma cópia da pasta e instalar outra versão por cima?

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, mas algumas tabelas acabaram sendo corrompidas, mas vou tentar criar elas igual a antes, vai ser difícil pois eram muitas, você não imagina minha raiva kkkk, mas obrigado.